# Audacity: Sliding Time Scale/Pitch Shift

Tags: music

I found a way to make to change music 440hz to 432hz.
Now, my problem it's i dont know the specifications to change to C528hz (A444hz).
Can anybody help me??

Thank you so much!!

Namaste <3

Comment: This question is slightly unclear. Could you be more precise? I'm assuming that you are talking about using Audacity (the software), though you made no mention of it other than in the title. If that is the case, then I am (again) assuming that your first sentence is talking about using the effect in Audacity called "Change Pitch...". Does your second sentence mean you want to change Audacity's default HZ for the note A? Please work on this question to make it understandable. That is if you ever check your account on this site anymore...

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear how you are going about this or what your goal is.

Do you want to set up an instrument so it is tuned to the "ancient solfege scale" so that your C5 = 528 Hz?

If that's the case there is more to this then just shifting your A 440, because this involves a very specific scale in a non-equal temperament tuning system.

The Solfeggio frequencies include:

```
01 = 174 Hz

02 = 285 Hz

Ut = 396 Hz

Re = 417 Hz

Mi = 528 Hz

Fa = 639 Hz

Sol = 741 Hz

La = 852 Hz

09 = 963 Hz
```

Source: http://myedenproject.wordpress.com/the-universe/solfeggio-scale/

Comment: I don't think this answers the question at all...

Comment: I think it does. I just think the question hasn't been well articulated.

Comment: :) Perhaps. However, it doesn't answer what I took the question to mean...